# Populating a ListView at run-time

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to populating a ListView at run-time with DynamicAppearance. The text parts work well, but the image is always the same as the last one. This  code adds to all items the same image. I want to add a image to just one item.

```pascal
procedure TfrmMain.crialista;
var
Aux1 : TStringDynArray; // Usado para trocar o nome.exe por nome_Icon
icone : string;          // Recebe o caminho completo para pegar o icone
Programa : Tprograma;  //  Contem todas as informações do programa , é passado para cada item da listbox.
Path : string;   //acho que não serve de nada
    // tb não usa pra nada
  Aux : integer;
 ARPrograma : array of TPrograma ;
  searchaux: string;
  Contador : integer;
begin
     listview1.Items.clear;

          TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
     begin
      QryEIS.Close;
      QryEIS.open; 
        Contador:= 0 ;

       SetLength(ARPrograma, QRyEIS.RecordCount );
      QryEIS.First;        
      while not QryEIS.Eof do
        begin
          QryDiretorio.Close;

          QryDiretorio.ParamByName('NomeDoSistema').Value:= QryEIS.FieldByName('DescricaoEIS').Value;
             QryDiretorio.Open;
          // Pegando o Icone do programa...

          if QryDiretorio.RecordCount = 0  then //escrever o erro aqui
            else
            begin

          aux1 :=     splitString( QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value, '.')  ;
          icone := 'F:\Sistemas\Icones\Launcher\' +aux1[0]+'_Icon.ico';
         // ImageList1.AddMasked(Bmp,clFuchsia);
          imagecontrol1.LoadFromFile(icone);
          ARPrograma[Contador].Icone := imagecontrol1.bitmap;


          ARPrograma[Contador].Nome:= QryDiretorio.FieldByName('NomeDoSistema').Value;
          ARPrograma[Contador].NomeExe :=  QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;
          // Caminho da unidade C (PathC) e da unidade F (Path)
          if QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value = 'T' then
          begin
        ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].DiretorioUser := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio   :=trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

          end
          else
          begin
          ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
          end ;



            aux := fileage(ARPrograma[Contador].path);
           ARPrograma[Contador].DataMod := FileDateToDateTime(aux);
         ARPrograma[Contador].Versao  :=  Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.path , '');
          if Programa.Versao <> '' then 
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.Versao , '.');
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;


              if fileExists(programa.pathC) then
            begin


              ARPrograma[Contador].VersaoC := Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.pathC , '');
               if Programa.VersaoC <> '' then   //  Mesma coisa do comentario do F:
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.VersaoC , '.');
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;
            end ;


        // Here i call the CriaFrama. 
          criaframa(ARPrograma[Contador], Contador);

           contador := Contador +1;
          end;


          QryEIS.Next;



          end;


         TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
         begin
// some visual thing....

         end);

     end).Start;
end;
procedure TfrmMain.CriaFrama(s: Tprograma; a : integer); 
var
  anitem : TListViewItem;
  txt : TListItemText;
  img : TListItemImage;
begin
  with FrmMain do
  begin
    anitem := Listview1.Items.Add;
    with anitem do
    begin
      txt := TListItemText(Objects.FindDrawable('Text1'));
      txt.Text := S.Nome;
      //the image  part
      img := TListItemImage(Objects.FindDrawable('Image2'));
      img.Bitmap := s.Icone;
    end;
  end;
```

Just for i can post the item...................

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: So, what is stopping you from simply skipping the `Bitmap` for all of the items? This code is *unconditionally* setting the `Bitmap` on every ListView item it creates. Add a *condition* to avoid that.

Comment: sorry , i think u miss understand. I need a bitmap in every item, but not the same bitmap on everyone. 
What i need to happen : 
item 1 get the bitmap 1 
Item 2 get the bitmap 2 
item 3 get the bitmap 3 
....
What is happen : 
item 1 get the bitmap 1
Item 2 get the bitmap 2 ( and replace the bitmap of item 1 with bitmap2) 
Item 3 get the bitmap 3 ( and replace all the others with bitmap3)
__________________________________________________________
in the end we got like 36 itens with the  right text but with the image of last one create.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible given the code you have shown. Each item is independent, each item has its own bitmap. Can you please show the code that is calling `CriaFrama()`? Without a [mcve] it is difficult to diagnose the problem

Comment: ok , I will post the code. I just edit the original post.

Comment: `ARPrograma[Contador].Icone := imagecontrol1.bitmap;` is pointing all of the array elements to the same `bitmap` object. You need to create a separate `TBitmap` object for each array element. Also, the thread's calls to `imagecontrol1.LoadFromFile()` and `criaframa()` need to be synchronized with the main UI thread. Although, if you make the thread create a new `TBitmap` instead of using `imagecontrol1`, you can use `TBitmap.LoadFromFile()` without syncing. Also, the 1-param `FileAge()` is deprecated, use the overloaded 2-param `FileAge()` that outputs a `TDateTime` instead.

Comment: On a side note, `ARPrograma` doesn't need to be a whole array, a single `TPrograma` will suffice, since the thread processes array elements 1 at a time. Also, `ARPrograma` is not used outside of the thread, so it should be a local variable inside of the thread.

Comment: I try the ´TBitmap.CreateFromFile()´ and works, thanks. 
So what u means to synchronize the   ´criaframa() ´?  
I make an array because I need to pass the path and make some comparisons with the versions info.  ( i don't  do that yet)

Comment: `CriaFrama()` is being called inside the worker thread, but it accesses the UI (`ListView1`) , so it needs to be synchronized with the UI thread (via `TThread.Synchronize()`). You can't access UI controls from outside of the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank so much for helping me, Remy Lebeau.
As he said in the comments, the problem was in pointing all items to the same bitmap and not synchronizing the segment when changing something in the user interface. (Not  sync generates some access violation errors)
The code:

```
    procedure TfrmMain.crialista;
var
Aux1 : TStringDynArray; 
icone : string;          
Path : string;   
Aux : integer;
ARPrograma : array of TPrograma ;
searchaux: string;
Contador : integer;
bitmap : FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
begin

     listview1.Visible := false;
 load_menu.Visible := true;
 Load_menu.Enabled :=  true;
     frmMain.LPrincipal.RemoveObject(0);
     listview1.Items.clear;
     searchaux:= searchBox1.Text;
     searchBox1.Text.Empty;
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
    var bitmap : FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
     begin
      QryEIS.Close;
      QryEIS.open; 
       Contador:= 0 ;
       SetLength(ARPrograma, QRyEIS.RecordCount );
      QryEIS.First;        
      while not QryEIS.Eof do
        begin
          QryDiretorio.Close;

          QryDiretorio.ParamByName('NomeDoSistema').Value  := 
            QryEIS.FieldByName('DescricaoEIS').Value;
             QryDiretorio.Open;


          if QryDiretorio.RecordCount = 0  then 
            else
            begin

                   TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin
           aux1 :=splitString( QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value, '.')  ;
           icone := 'F:\Sistemas\Icones\Launcher\' +aux1[0]+'_Icon.ico';
           BitMap := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.CreateFromFile(icone);
           ARPrograma[Contador].Icone := bitmap ;

        end);



          ARPrograma[Contador].Nome:= QryDiretorio.FieldByName('NomeDoSistema').Value;
          ARPrograma[Contador].NomeExe :=  QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

          if QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value = 'T' then
          begin
        ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
            ARPrograma[Contador].DiretorioUser := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+qryNome.FieldByname('NomeUsuario').Value;
             ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio   :=trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
             ARPrograma[Contador].SingleUser := QryDiretorio.FieldByName('SingleUser').Value ;

          end
          else
          begin
          ARPrograma[Contador].path := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Origem').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].pathC := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value)+'\'+trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('Sistema').Value);
          ARPrograma[Contador].Diretorio := trim(QryDiretorio.FieldByName('destino').Value);
          end ;
          //Pega a versão do .exe da unidade F:


            aux := fileage(ARPrograma[Contador].path); // Do not use that , use the 2 params FileAge, for more information check the comments
           ARPrograma[Contador].DataMod := FileDateToDateTime(aux);
         ARPrograma[Contador].Versao  :=  Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.path , '');
          if Programa.Versao <> '' then //caso não seja nulo , coloca no array de integer , para ficar mais facil de comparar na hora de atualizar. (fica em Udetalhes)
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.Versao , '.');
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
             ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVer[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;

              if fileExists(programa.pathC) then
            begin


              ARPrograma[Contador].VersaoC := Sto_GetFmtFileVersion(Programa.pathC , '');
               if Programa.VersaoC <> '' then  
              begin
              aux1 := splitString (Programa.VersaoC , '.');
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[1] := strtoint(aux1[0]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[2] := strtoint(aux1[1]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[3] := strtoint(aux1[2]);
              ARPrograma[Contador].iVerC[4] := strtoint(aux1[3]);
              end;
            end ;


          TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin
             criaframa(ARPrograma[Contador], Contador);

        end);


           contador := Contador +1;
          end;

          QryEIS.Next;



          end;


        TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        begin

          listview1.Visible := true;
          load_menu.Visible := false;
          Load_menu.Enabled :=  false;
           searchBox1.Text :='';
        end);

     end).Start;
end;
```

The other part still the same.